# ProviderNotFoundException was thrown

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

This is the code I'm using

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
if (user == null) {
  return LoginPage();
} else {
  return MyHomePage();
}
}
}
```

and the user file has

```
class User {
final String uid;
User({this.uid});
}
```

And I am getting this error:

The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Wrapper(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Wrapper Widget
This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
  Make sure that Wrapper is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the User object somewhere in a widget above Wrapper

Something like this:

```
Provider(
  create: (_) => User(),
  child: Wrapper()
)
```

https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/